# Audition cc bus not receiving input

Tags: mixing, aux-sends, adobe-audition

So I made a duplicate of my session which has 4 tracks in it - 2 dialogue, a bus and a bk music track.
For some strange reason my 2nd dialogue track won't send to my bus? It doesn't make any sense as the simple setup worked flawlessly in the original session.
Basically the bus receives audio from track 1 not 2??? Any thoughts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind I solved it.

[image]

The trick is to make sure that audition isn't re-routing the bus to the master track and that correct audio tracks are routing sends to the correct bus, located on top of the mixer. The Bus then routes to either another bus or the master track.